# How to stop editing cell after removing a row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell

In my JTable when a new row is added, automatically a "JTextString" cell is selected to be edited. If the new value entered in the cell fails the validation, this new row is supposed to be removed.

In my DefacultCellEditor instance I have:

```
        @Override
        public boolean stopCellEditing(){
            /* do something */

                if (/* failed validation */) {
                    super.stopCellEditing();
                    myTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                    myTable.removeLastRow();
                    return true;
                }
           ....
         }
```

Actually when the validation fails, the last row is removed:

```
    model.removeRow(model.getRowCount() - 1);
```

but the same cell in the above row is editing. How can I stop the editing and leaving all the rows deselected?

Comment: it's wrong to let an editor _change_ the target: it's designed to _notify_ on being ready, nothing else. Instead, let it report any validation error (at least return false on stopEditing, and or fire a custom signal)) and let the caller (or another listener) handle any logic as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted a sample of code that could be run directly.  Since you didn't, I haven't tested this out - I have no idea what other changes you've made in your table model.

Change

```
super.stopCellEditing();
```

to

```
super.cancelCellEditing();
```

and remove the line with `clearSelection`.